# Force per velocity per time squared signifies what?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Anyone know what force per velocity per time squared signifies? It has to do with magnetic fields.

I was doing dimensional analysis and it popped up.

(Charge is assigned units of force and the rest just follows)

$ E \quad = \quad \frac{q_1}{d^2}  = \quad \frac{F}{d^2} $

$\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \quad = \quad \frac{d^2}{F}$

$F \quad = \quad \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \cdot q_2 \cdot E \quad = \quad \frac{d^2}{F} \frac{q_2 q_1}{d^2} \quad = \quad \frac{d^2}{F} \frac{F F}{d^2}$

$B \quad = \quad \frac{I_1}{d} \quad = \quad \frac{q_1}{t d} \quad = \quad \frac{F}{t d} \quad = \quad \frac{F / v}{t^2}$

$\mu \quad = \quad \frac{t^2}{F}$

$F \quad = \quad \mu \cdot I_2 \cdot B \cdot d \quad = \quad \frac{t^2}{F} \frac{q_2}{t} \frac{q_1}{t d} d \quad = \quad \frac{t^2}{F} \frac{F}{t} \frac{F}{t d} d$

$c \quad = \quad \sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}} \quad = \quad \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{F} \frac{F}{t^2}} \quad = \quad \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{t^2}} = \frac{d}{t}$

https://tok.fandom.com/wiki/Template:Electromagnetism_header

Comment: You should probably have mentioned that these equations come from a page advocating for an alternate system of units from SI.

Comment: SI is only one of many systems. https://tok.fandom.com/wiki/Gaussian_units

Comment: And it didnt come from that page. It  came from me. That page also came from me

Comment: @REmery, I'm well aware there exist many unit systems. But if you're going to advocate for creating a new one you should say clearly how it will improve our understanding of physics. (And this is not Guassian units because Guassian units don't equate charge and force).

Comment: I didnt say it was Gaussian. It is better because it has fewer base units and makes equations more intuitive.

Comment: How is it more intuitive if the person who invented it has to come ask about the significance of the units of magnetic field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117409/discussion-between-r-emery-and-the-photon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A charged particle moving in a magnetic field experiences a force that is proportional to its velocity. So units of force per velocity make sense.

But I have no idea where time squared comes from.

Rate of change of current gives "per time squared"

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{F/v}{t^2}$ is nothing but Force per meter per second. It is just written differently.

$\frac{F/v}{t^2} = \frac{t F/ d}{t^2}$

where $d$ is for meter (the same letter that you used). then,

$\frac{F/v}{t^2} = \frac{F/ d}{t}$

$\frac{F/v}{t^2} = \frac{F}{d \times t}$

Note that $d \times t$ just means $d$ times $t$. That is Force per meter per second.

Comment: Wolfram says its power per area

Comment: I went with time squared because the magnetic constant mu contains time squared. (And the electric constant contains distance squared)

Comment: Indeed you could also call it power per area if you'd like to $\frac{F/d}{t}= \frac{Fd/t}{d^2}=\frac{P}{A}$

Comment: Along the lines of @R.Emery , Power-per-area has metric units of Watt/m^2 (as in the solar irradiance of about 1400 W/m^2) . An alternative to Triatticus's proof is $\frac{(F/v)}{t^2}=\frac{Fv}{v^2t^2}=\frac{P}{x^2}=\frac{P}{A}$.

Answer (score -1):

You have already written in the question that $F/v/t^2$ is is another way of writing to express the units of magnetic field.

Comment: Yes and if I knew what force per velocity per time squared signified then it would tell me something about the magnetic field. Mass times velocity is momentum. Mass times velocity squared is energy. What is force per velocity per time squared?